# How to get_formatted_order_total() if I know order_number in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, formatted

I want to display 'Price' and 'Payment method' for a specific order with get_formatted_order_total(), all I know is order_number.

What is the best way to get this formatted order total for a specific order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a public function , you can use ,

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$string = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
```